# Incorrect text displayed on job filter and recent searches

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, filtering

I was looking at the job search feature and wanted to look for something local to me, so I narrowed it down to 20km of me. That appears to work fine, however the history shows up something different, in my recent searches I get:

> Jobs within 20 miles of location

So, is it in miles or KM?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good spot! We had a subtle bug that meant distance units weren't respected all the time. The recent search indicates the actual search that was run. I've fixed it and pushed a new build.

Thanks for the report :)